# set session for object in Rspec integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, integration-testing, rspec2

I have the following in my controller:

```
def create
    @board = Board.find(session[:board])
    @greeting = @board.Greetings.build(params[:greeting])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @greeting.save
         format.js   { render :action => "success" }
      else
        format.js    { render :action => "failure" }
      end
    end
  end
```

In my rspec selenium test I want to set the session for the board. But it seems I can't

```
  describe "greeting creation" do

     before(:each) do
        @board = Factory(:board)
        session[:board] = @board.id
      end
```

THis gives the following error:

```
  Failure/Error: session[:board] = @board.id
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `session' for nil:NilClass
```

How can I set the session so this test works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue and 'solved' it by using ApplicationController.session[:key].

But now I get the error `TypeError:
  can't convert Symbol into Integer
level_spec.rb:7:in`[]='`

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the fixture is being called correctly? They're usually plural, like `factories(:board)`.

You could try just setting it explicitly in the test to see if you can even set the session, instead of trying to load from a fixture. If that works, then you know the problem is in loading the fixture.

Comment: I am using factory girl gem so the call is correct. I need to set the session in the controller for my test to work. I can't access the session object it seems. Any ideas?